# Extract the minimum matrix of a set of matrix inside a list in r

Tags: r

I have a list with N matrix in R:

```
mylist <- list(a=matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2), b=matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2), c=matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2))
```

I would like to extract a matrix with the minimum values in each `(i,j)` for the three matrix (in my real example all matrix have the same dimensions).

I can do it manually with
`pmin(a,b,c)`, but it would be impractical for my case, because I have several matrix in the list.

I tried with

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) pmin(x))
```

but I get the original list.
Any suggestions?

Thank you.
Cheers.

Comment: `rnorm(1:10, ncol=2)` is not valid R syntax. Please edit your post. If you use random data, set a fixed seed. Also provide your expected output for the sample data you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
am <- matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2)
bm <- matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2)
cm <- matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2)

mylist <- list(a=am, b=bm, c=cm)

working <- pmin(am, bm, cm) # What you stated is working

new <- do.call(pmin, mylist)  # Calling for all elements of a list

identical(working, new) # verify if the new answer outputs the same
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MilloMarinE Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: @MilloMarinE and you didn't reply to the wrong question, the answer of the other guy was just edited fast (if you didn't close your browser you can see the old answer by returning pages).

Comment: That's what happened then. I got confused, sorry. Thank you again!

Comment: @MilloMarinE No problem! thats not your fault :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reduce`

```
 # creating a list of matrices
    set.seed(1)
    mylist <- list(a=matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2), 
                   b=matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2), 
                   c=matrix(rnorm(1:10), ncol=2))


# getting min
> Reduce("pmin", mylist)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8204684
[2,]  0.1836433 -0.1557955
[3,] -0.8356286 -1.4707524
[4,] -2.2146999 -0.4781501
[5,]  0.3295078 -0.3053884
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, that doesn't solve my problem. I would like the result to be a matrix of the same dimensions as a, b and c, but with the minimum value in each [i,j]. the result of pmin(a,b,c) provides a clear example of what I'm looking for, Thanx again.

Comment: @MilloMarinE you said `pmin(a,b,c)` works, and `Reduce("pmin", mylist)` gives the same result as `pmin(a,b,c)`, so I don't understand  your point. It even gives the same dimensions of original matrices.

Comment: I am sorry, for some reason I repplied to the wrong question. Your answer does exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MilloMarinE you can say "thank you" by upvoting correct answers and accepting the one that better solves your problema by clicking on the tick mark right beside the answer.

Comment: Done. Thank you,